# Share Storyboard between iOS App and its Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a iOS App and a corresponding action extension.
I managed to create a app group to share the NSUserDefaults between the app and the extension.

Now i want to reuse some parts of my storyboard from the main app in the extension. How can I share the storyboard between the app and the extension?
Can anyone provide an example in Swift?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try adding the storyboard file to the your extension target? What were the results?

Comment: I tried it. But how can I embedd the shared storyboard into my existing extension storyboard? How can I include it within a View Container?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to share views between your app and extension, you would need to create xibs for each view you wanted to share. These xibs would then be compiled in to a framework that is used by both your app and extension.

It also may be possible to create a separate storyboard with the shared views, then put this storyboard in to the framework.

The xib route seemed more correct to me, as you won't be composing a scene with the storyboard, just throwing a bunch of views in it.